# Basis for curvillinear coordinate systems.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading through Geometry of Physics - Frankel and in the preface of the latest edition, Frankel defines a curve $C_i$ through a point $p$ parametrized by $u^j=constant$, $j\neq i$, with curvilinear coordinates $u^i$. For example, in curvilinear coordinates $x^1 =r$,$x^2=\theta$, $u^1=1$,$u^2=\theta$ He goes on to claim $\partial p/ \partial  u^i$ defines a basis for all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For the example above, a point $p$ could be $(1,\pi)$. How can the basis for  $\mathbb{R}^2$ be what Frankel calls the tangent vectors $\partial p/ \partial u^i$?

Comment: Have you computed these vectors?  Have you tested whether they form a basis?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something...isn't $\partial p/\partial \theta = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think the issue here is that it's not clear what the text means by $p$.  Let $p$ be a *function* of the coordinates $(r,\theta)$ such that $p(r,\theta)$ is the position vector associated with that point.

Then, the derivatives $\partial p/\partial r$ and $\partial p/\partial \theta$ should clearly be vectors, and you should be able to show that they form a basis.